# problem in writing to a file

Tags: c++, file-handling

Guys I wrote the following code for implementing a phonebook in c++
What I am doing is first take input from three files containing names, address and phone number(u may not look at the entire code) just look at the bottom

Now I give user to add contacts to add during runtime and these values are stored in a class.
Now I erase the files containing names, address and numbers and write new data into them using ofstream which will be retrieved when user again runs the "phonebook"

however i am not able to see any input into the files after program has run once and I added a few values during the runtime.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

```
    #include<iostream>//Include Header Files   
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class contact{

    public:

         string name;//ALL CLASS VARIABLES ARE PUBLIC

         int phonenumber;

         string address;

         contact(){//Constructor

         name= "Noname";

         phonenumber= 0;

         address= "Noaddress";

    }


    };

    int main(){

         contact *d;

         d= new contact[200];

         string name,add;

         int choice,modchoice,k=0;//Variable for switch statement

         int phno,phno1;

         int i=0;
         int initsize=0, i1=0;//i is declared as a static int variable

         bool flag=false,flag_no_blank=false;


         //TAKE DATA FROM FILES.....
         //We create 3 files names, phone numbers, Address and then abstract the data from these files first!

         fstream f1;
         fstream f2;
         fstream f3;

         string file_input_name; 
         string file_input_address;

         int file_input_number;


         f1.open("./names");

         while(f1>>file_input_name){

              d[i].name=file_input_name;

              i++;

         }
         initsize=i;

         f2.open("./numbers");

         while(f2>>file_input_number){

              d[i1].phonenumber=file_input_number;
              i1++;

         }

         i1=0;


         f3.open("./address");

         while(f3>>file_input_address){

              d[i1].address=file_input_address;

              i1++;

         }





         cout<<"\tWelcome to the phone Directory\n";//Welcome Message
         do{    
              //do-While Loop Starts
              cout<<"Select :\n1.Add New Contact\n2.Update Existing Contact\n3.Display All Contacts\n4.Search for a Contact\n5.Delete a  Contact\n6.Exit PhoneBook\n\n\n";//Display all options


              cin>>choice;//Input Choice from user



              switch(choice){//Switch Loop Starts

              case 1:{

                   i++;//increment i so that values are now taken from the program and stored as different variables 
                   i1++;

               do{

                        cout<<"\nEnter The Name\n";

                cin>>name;

                if(name==" "){cout<<"Blank Entries are not allowed";
                                 flag_no_blank=true;

                }

               }while(flag_no_blank==true);


                   flag_no_blank=false;



               d[i].name=name;

               cout<<"\nEnter the Phone Number\n";

                   cin>>phno;

                   d[i1].phonenumber=phno;



               cout<<"\nEnter the address\n";


                   cin>>add;

                   d[i1].address=add;

               i1++;

                   i++;

                   break;//Exit Case 1 to the main menu
              }

              case 2:   {

                   cout<<"\nEnter the name\n";//Here it is assumed that no two contacts can have same contact number or address but may have the same name.

               cin>>name;

               int k=0,val;

               cout<<"\n\nSearching.........\n\n";

               for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){


                    if(d[j].name==name){

                     k++;           

                     cout<<k<<".\t"<<d[j].name<<"\t"<<d[j].phonenumber<<"\t"<<d[j].address<<"\n\n";

                     val=j;                 

                     }

                 }


                 char ch;

                 cout<<"\nTotal of "<<k<<" Entries were found....Do you wish to edit?\n";

                 string staticname;

                 staticname=d[val].name;

                 cin>>ch;

                 if(ch=='y'|| ch=='Y'){

                      cout<<"Which entry do you wish to modify ?(enter the old telephone number)\n";

                      cin>>phno;

                  for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){

                       if(d[j].phonenumber==phno && staticname==d[j].name){

                            cout<<"Do you wish to change the name?\n";

                        cin>>ch;

                            if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y'){

                             cout<<"Enter new name\n";

                         cin>>name;

                         d[j].name=name;

                        }

                        cout<<"Do you wish to change the number?\n";

                            cin>>ch;

                        if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y'){

                             cout<<"Enter the new number\n";

                         cin>>phno1;

                         d[j].phonenumber=phno1;

                         }

                                     cout<<"Do you wish to change the address?\n";

                         cin>>ch;

                         if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y'){

                              cout<<"Enter the new address\n";

                          cin>>add;

                          d[j].address=add;

                         }

                        }               

                   }

                      }

                      break;

                 }

             case 3 : {

                  cout<<"\n\tContents of PhoneBook:\n\n\tNames\tNumbers\tAddresses\n";

                  for(int t=0;t<=i;t++){

                       if(d[t].name=="Noname") continue;

                       cout<<".\t"<<d[t].name<<"\t"<<d[t].phonenumber<<"\t"<<d[t].address<<"\n";

                  }

                      cout<<"\n\n\n\n";

                  break;

                 }

             case 4:{
                  cout<<"Enter a name to search\n";

                  cin>>name;

                      cout<<"\n\nSearching.........\n\n";

                  for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){

                      if(d[j].name==name){

                       k++;         

                   cout<<k<<".\t"<<d[j].name<<"\t"<<d[j].phonenumber<<"\t"<<d[j].address<<"\n\n";

                   int val=j;                   

                  }

             }

             cout<<"\nA total of "<<k<<" contact names were found having the name"<<name;

             break;
            }
            case 6:{

                 cout<<"\n\nClosing the phonebook...Visit Again\n";

             flag=true;

                 break;

            }

            case 5: {

                 cout<<"\nEnter the contact-name\n";//Here it is assumed that no two contacts can have same contact number or address but may have the same name.

             cin>>name;

             int k=0,val;

             cout<<"\n\nSearching.........\n\n";

             for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){

                      if(d[j].name==name){
                       k++;         

                   cout<<k<<".\t"<<d[j].name<<"\t"<<d[j].phonenumber<<"\t"<<d[j].address<<"\n\n";
                                                                                      val=j;                    

                  }

             }


             char ch;

             cout<<"\nTotal of "<<k<<" Entries were found....Do you wish to delete?\n";

             if(k==0) break;

             string staticname;

             staticname=d[val].name;

             cin>>ch;

             if(ch=='y'|| ch=='Y'){

                  cout<<"Which entry do you wish to delete ?(enter the old telephone number)\n";

                  cin>>phno;

                  for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){

                       if(d[j].phonenumber==phno && staticname==d[j].name){

                                val=j;                  

                   }

                      }

                      for(int j=val;j<=i-1;j++){

                           d[j].name=d[j+1].name;


                           d[j].phonenumber=d[j+1].phonenumber;


                           d[j].address=d[j+1].address;

                      }

                      d[i].name="Noname";


                      d[i].phonenumber=0;


                      d[i].address="Noaddress";

                 }


                 break;

            }

       }
  }


  while(flag==false);

  std::ofstream f4("./names");

  f4.close();

  std::ofstream f5("./numbers");

  f5.close();

  std::ofstream f6("./address");

  f6.close();

  f1.close();

  f2.close();

  f3.close();

  ofstream f7,f8,f9;

  f7.open("names");

  f8.open("numbers");

  f9.open("address");
  int y=0;

  string w;

  w=d[0].name;

  while(f7<<w && y<=i){

  if(w=="Noname") y++; continue;

  y++;

  w=d[y].name;

  }

  y=0;
  int v;
  v=d[0].phonenumber;
  while(f8<<v && y<=i){
       if(v==0){y++; continue;}
       y++;
       v=d[y].phonenumber;
  }

  y=0;

  string u;
  u=d[0].address;

  while(f9<<u && y<=i ){

       if(u=="Noaddress"){

            continue;
            y++;
       }

       y++;

       u=d[y].address;

  }

  return 0;

  }
```

Comment: I clicked the code formatting button for you, but please re-copy from a viewer that preserves indentation tabs. Also, please boil it down a bit, that's incredibly long.

Comment: @potato: i mentioned that u may not look at the entire code...upper part is running perfectly smoothly but i just have problem in writing data to files, thats it

Comment: @Frustrated: If you don't have writing working, how did you test reading?

Comment: Your code is so horribly formatted, most people will not even try to scan to the lower part.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me with f1, f2, f3, close(f1,f2,f3,), f7 f8 f9 ??? WTF

Comment: @Frustrated: it is pointless to say "do not look at the code I'm showing you".  It would be more sensible to say "I think the code near the top is working", but very often, when something goes wrong in section A of the code and you cannot see the problem in section A, it is because the trouble is in some other section B of the code that you thought was OK.

Comment: @Frustrated: there is a marvellous invention in computer science called a 'function'.  Learn how to write and use them.  Your code desparately needs to use some functions to do units of work, and to stop your code marching off the RHS of the screen.

Comment: @Jonathan: have a look. I'm afraid the code is clearly fishy all around (and that is putting it very mildly)

Comment: @Sehe: I looked long enough - file streams f1..f9 are bad code smells. Separate files for names, numbers and addresses is weird.  Using variously "./names" and "names" is not good.  I've not even tried to understand what the input switch is up to; it is too messily indented.  I'm not keen on the mechanism used to delete a row from the array.  I'm assuming the array is an array and not a vector since I don't see a relevant header included. (513 lines in the original; 276 of those are blank.  Too much vertical white space!) Etc.

Comment: As an aside... if you practiced TDD, it would save you a whole lot of debugging! And probably have prevented a fair chunk of this code being written in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Does C++ handle I/O errors automatically? Psychically? If not, then where are your error-return handlers? Just askin'.

**EDIT in response to the OP's comment:** Yes, I understand, but ordinarily if data is not being written to the file, the file system returns an error code that tries to tell you ***why*** it was not written. But you decided to ignore what the file system had to say. My question, which I'd hoped would give you a hint, should have been:

"If you don't check the file-write-call return codes, you will have a good, long hike trying to debug your program. Please check those error return codes and tell us what they are. This is standard ***and required*** programming practice, after all, and if  you don't follow standard, required practice then your only hope is to consult the gypsy fortune-teller on the corner.

"SO: what are the codes being returned from each and every file-I/O call?"

Try that and tell us more. And thanks for the downvote: I needed that.

Comment: there is no error, just that data is not being written to file

Comment: @Frustrated Coder -- (and I quote)  "there is no error, just that data is not being written to the file." Oh, of course. I missed that subtle distinction.

Comment: +1 A Paranoid Programming Philosophy (which is a **required** practice) involves handling all exceptions, checking all API return codes, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

I can see why you are frustrated, coder. This is frustrating code.

> <strike>while(flag==false)</strike> (as per Jonathans comment this isn't as blatantly bad as it appeared. It still is bad that it is even hard to judge the real junk from the rest of the mess... :)

WTF? Just don't hit '6' to exit, or you will be frying your CPU for free

> It was still burning 100% of CPU and filling /tmp at a hazardous pace anyway. I guess, it is not called an infinite loop (because it exits as soon as the filesystem is full). Thank god, /tmp is on tmpfs (size 4g) and I have 8g of ram available :)

Storing the names, numbers and addresses in separate files... hm probably a good idea.

One test run I had it writing 3.7G to address :) ("NoaddressNoaddressNoaddressNoaddressNo....") Just sweet to make it crash because on load, the buffer to receive address in (obviously called `d`) is precisely 200 records.

Frankly this code should move to TheDailyWTF. Pronto Pronto!

This code can not be fixed. Period

Comment: Fortunately, '`flag == true`' when the 'infinite loop' is hit.  Or do I mean unfortunately.

Comment: you wouldn't know it from the ... layout ... but that `while` condition is the tail end of a `do { ... } while (flag == true);` loop.  I don't think I've ever seen a while like that separated from its close brace by three blank lines before (and I won't be able to say that again!).

Comment: @Jonathan: you are so right. The infinite loop writing `address` until my filesystem was depleted mut have been caused by one of the many other opportunities for failure....

Answer (score 2):

btw.

```
while(f7<<w && y<=i){
    if(w=="Noname") 
        y++;          // <- proper indention is king
    continue;
    y++;              // <- never reached
    w=d[y].name;      // <- never reached
}

while(f8<<v && y<=i){
    if(v==0) {
        y++; 
        continue;
    }
    y++;
    v=d[y].phonenumber;
}

while(f9<<u && y<=i ){
    if(u=="Noaddress") {
        continue;
        y++;         // <- never reached
    }
    y++;
    u=d[y].address;
}
```

Comment: And there's more to the problems than the erratic code.  It is meant to skip the invalid entries, but it only checks whether the entry was invalid after writing it successfully.  The while loops should be written as a for loop, and the output should be in a conditional in the body of the loop.  (And I know that's the original code you're quoting!)

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of things wrong with this program.  Lets try to fix a few for a start and then build on that.

Firstly, what does a name look like?  Does it have a space, like "Fred Jones" or maybe a comma like "Jones,Fred".  Maybe many parts like "Chan Kong Sang".

If you permit spaces, then you can't read it in with "<<".  Maybe you can put one name per line and read it in with getline().

Try writing a small program that just reads in names and stores them.  You can create the file using an editor.  Once that works, we can build on it.